# how to fix deadlock during concurrent delete

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I have multiple background jobs that need to batch delete many rows concurrently. Basically they are the same job, but partitioned. Currently, I am getting intermittent deadlock on an index. This is not an issue as the job will restart and re-run, but it is an expensive operation so I would not like to have is start over.

How do I allow multiple batch deletes concurrently without a deadlock?
I am okay to trade it with blocking if necessary.

The query looks like this:

```
DECLARE @rowCount INT = 1
WHILE @rowCount > 0
BEGIN
    DELETE TOP 5000 v
    FROM dbo.Values v
    JOIN @FK1Filter fk1 on fk1.Id = v.FK1Id
    JOIN @FK2Filter fk2 on fk2.Id = ISNULL(v.FK2Id, 0)
    WHERE @Start <= v.Timestamp AND v.Timestamp < @End;

    SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
END
```

The index used is `IX_FK1Id_Timestamp_FK2Id`. I also tried with index `IX_FK1Id_Timestamp` but both exhibit the same locking issue. I also tried to change the batch size but it seems to have no effect.

Update:

Here is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Values (
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FK1Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FK4Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [FK3Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FK2Id] [int] NULL,
    [Value] [decimal](19, 6) NULL,
    [String] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Values] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [Id] ASC
    )
)
```

And here is the index I have on it:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Values_FK1Id_Timestamp] ON dbo.[Values] (
    [FK1Id] ASC,
    [Timestamp] ASC
) INCLUDE (
    [Id],
    [FK4Id],
    [FK2Id]
)
```

Here is the last deadlock graph I had

[image]

```html
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process373c108">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process373c108" taskpriority="0" logused="17352" waitresource="KEY: 8:72057594079543296 (eea42a343525)" waittime="1281" ownerId="122202058" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-07-08T11:12:14.327" XDES="0x17a7966f0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="13" kpid="23808" status="suspended" spid="56" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-07-08T11:12:14.910" lastbatchcompleted="2021-07-08T11:12:14.887" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.887" clientapp="webSettlementRetail" hostname="HERMESR-D" hostpid="815730986" loginname="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="122202058" currentdb="8" currentdbname="THE_database" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="5" stmtstart="426" stmtend="1038" sqlhandle="0x02000000106fe6253b2e00886a5d6c9caad86886955875220000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@batchSize int,@startDate datetime2(7),@endDate datetime2(7),@FK1Filter [dbo].[Udt_Ids] READONLY,@FK2Filter [dbo].[Udt_Ids] READONLY)
                DECLARE @rowCount INT = 1;
                WHILE (@rowCount &gt; 0)
                BEGIN
DELETE TOP(@batchSize) v 
                        FROM dbo.Values v
                        INNER JOIN @FK1Filter fk1s ON fk1s.Id = v.FK1Id
                        INNER JOIN @FK2Filter fk2s ON fk2s.Id = ISNULL(v.FK2Id, 0)
                        WHERE @startDate &lt;= v.Timestamp AND v.Timestamp &lt; @endDate;

                    SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
                END
    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process3cba4e8" taskpriority="0" logused="417908" waitresource="KEY: 8:72057594079543296 (db465acb4fb4)" waittime="1270" ownerId="122202233" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2021-07-08T11:12:14.440" XDES="0xaf82f030" lockMode="U" schedulerid="16" kpid="21696" status="suspended" spid="74" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2021-07-08T11:12:15.087" lastbatchcompleted="2021-07-08T11:12:15.050" lastattention="2021-07-08T11:11:40.277" clientapp="webSettlementRetail" hostname="HERMESR-D" hostpid="815730986" loginname="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="122202233" currentdb="8" currentdbname="THE_database" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="5" stmtstart="426" stmtend="1038" sqlhandle="0x02000000106fe6253b2e00886a5d6c9caad86886955875220000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@batchSize int,@startDate datetime2(7),@endDate datetime2(7),@FK1Filter [dbo].[Udt_Ids] READONLY,@FK2Filter [dbo].[Udt_Ids] READONLY)
                DECLARE @rowCount INT = 1;
                WHILE (@rowCount &gt; 0)
                BEGIN
DELETE TOP(@batchSize) v 
                        FROM dbo.Values v
                        INNER JOIN @FK1Filter fk1s ON fk1s.Id = v.FK1Id
                        INNER JOIN @FK2Filter fk2s ON fk2s.Id = ISNULL(v.FK2Id, 0)
                        WHERE @startDate &lt;= v.Timestamp AND v.Timestamp &lt; @endDate;

                    SET @rowCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
                END
    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594079543296" dbid="8" objectname="THE_database.dbo.Values" indexname="IX_Values_FK1Id_Timestamp" id="lock100e1b980" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594079543296">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process3cba4e8" mode="X"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process373c108" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594079543296" dbid="8" objectname="THE_database.dbo.Values" indexname="IX_Values_FK1Id_Timestamp" id="lock16f2d7080" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594079543296">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process373c108" mode="U"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process3cba4e8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Comment: You need to show your deadlock graph.

Comment: Something doesn't add up: how are you using table variables in different connections concurrently, that isn't possible. For help with deadlocks, you need to show us your table and index definitions, and share the deadlock graph and the actual execution plan. Otherwise it's impossible to say for sure what's causing this

Comment: I have added the deadlock graph. I don't have the execution plan or not sure how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

A table variable cannot have indexes. You can increase the speed of the delete by using temp tables and creating clustered indexes on the temp tables. I have experienced massive increases in execution speed by doing so. You may also explore creating an index on v.timestamp so the where portion uses a seek instead of a scan.

You can also try dropping the indexes on dbo.values during the delete and then recreating the indexes after the delete is done. You should time it and you may discover that the total time required is much faster then leaving the indexes alone.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, I meant job performance rather than the sql delete performance. When the delete operation deadlocks, the job is restarted and it is an expensive operation that is why I need to avoid it.

Comment: Deadlocks occur because it is running slow and you end up using the same resource another process is using. If you execute fast many fewer deadlocks occur.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using temporary tables instead of table variables and create then with the `Id` column as a unique clustered index.

In addition to utilising the key-values in a sorted fashion and possibly a *merge* join strategy, using a temp table will yield proper statistics and cardinality estimates to help SQL Server build an optimal plan, which you simply don't get using table variables.

I would also suggest reducing the batch size to below 5000. SQL Server has a lock-escalation threshold around 5000 rows above which it says sod-it and chooses to lock the table  instead.

I would also suggest trying following construct

```
with RowsToDelete as (
  SELECT TOP 5000 v.*
  FROM dbo.Values v
  JOIN #FK1Filter fk1 on fk1.Id = v.FK1Id
  JOIN #FK2Filter fk2 on fk2.Id = ISNULL(v.FK2Id, 0)
  WHERE @Start <= v.Timestamp AND v.Timestamp < @End
  ORDER BY V.Timestamp
)
DELETE from RowsToDelete
```

Ideally you would have an index on `Timestamp`, preferably clustered for the best performance - other suggestions would need seeing your actual tables' schema and existing indexes.

Provided each separate execution targets clearly distinct sets of rows this will hopefully yield an improvement.